# The same code but different behavior for AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, directive

I wrote a directive 'xxx' and it has different behavior on a browser and Jasmine testing framework:

```
someapp.directive('xxx', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        x: '=xxx'
      },
      template: '<div>Hello World {{x}}</div>',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    };
  });
```

For browser:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div xxx="name"></div>
</body>

someapp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Test';
});
```

It will show "Hello World Test" on the screen in a browser.
If in the link function, I add one line:

```
global_var = element;
```

and add one line of HTML

```
<button onclick="javascript:alert(global_var.text());">Test</button>
```

It will also pop up the alert dialog to show the text "Hello World Test".

However, for Jasmine testing framework:

```
beforeEach(module('someapp'));

var element,
  scope;

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  scope.name = 'Test';
}));

it('should expand "x"', inject(function ($compile) {
  element = angular.element('<div xxx="name"></div>');
  element = $compile(element)(scope); 
  expect(element.text()).toBe('Hello World Test');
}));
```

It will report the error: expected "Hello World {{x}}" to be "Hello World Test"

Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the changes to take effect (i.e. for Angular to do its thing) you need to call **[`scope.$apply()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)** or **[`scope.$digest()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest)**.
(**[`$digest()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest)** would suffice for this scenario, but in a more complex situation (involving parent scopes etc) you might need to call (the more expensive) **[`$apply()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)** method.)

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/3E5rC/)**.